# What's the deal with Flash Gordon and tree stump reference?

Tags: flash-gordon

Tripp webcomic (which i BEG you to please ask some questions about - it's on-topic :) had a hover over in 11/21/2013 "[Claw Game](http://www.trippcomic.com/archives/archive/claw-game)" strip that stated:

> Actually, Hell probably does have a prize door, something akin to sticking your hand in that tree stump in Flash Gordon.

What was that Flash Gordon "tree stump" bit in reference to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the comic is referencing the [Flash Gordon (1980) movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_%28film%29) where Prince Barin doesn't like or trust Flash so he makes him play "Outer Space Russian Roulette" (so to speak).

Prince Barin basically makes Flash stick his hand in a hole and if the creature inside bites him, he's dead.

Here's a clip of the first part of the scene describing the ritual of manhood.

I can't find the rest where Barin makes Flash stick his hand in.

Comment: I think the same scene is in the tv series too.

Comment: Flash doesn't cheat in the scene. Indeed I'd say cheating would be contrary to the whole character of Flash.

Comment: @djim Daniel's correct: he didn't cheat sticking his hand in. He did however pretend that he was stung, then used that to escape.

Comment: @Andreas: Yes! I remember now; thanks!